# Excel: combining tables while turning columns into rows

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have these tables (under DATA), each table is in a separate sheet in the same file.
I'm trying to figure out a way to merge them a single report similar to the green table (Desired Outcome)

Any advise? My issue is turning Brand A/B/C into unique Rows

[here's an image of the data tables & desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8U3D1.png)

Answer (score 0):

Load one of the tables into powerquery (data .. from table/range) 
Click select the two left columns, then right click ... Unpivot other columns
File close and load, connection only
Repeat for other tables
Combine the four resulting queries back in excel
Use can use data .. get data ... combine queries .. append  , or in a new query, use Table.Combine()

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with `Power Query` to accomplish this task follow the steps,

[image]

---

• Select some cell in your `Data Table`,

• `Data Tab` => `Get&Transform` => `From Table/Range`,

• When the `PQ Editor` opens: `Home` => `Advanced Editor`,

• Make note of all the 4 Tables Names,

• Paste the `M Code` below in place of what you see.

---

```
let
    //DataOne
    SourceOne = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataOne"]}[Content],
    DataTypeOne = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceOne,{{"#", type any}, {"Region", type text}, {"Desc.", type text}, {"Brand A", Int64.Type}, {"Brand B", Int64.Type}, {"Brand C", Int64.Type}}),

    //DataTwo
    SourceTwo = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataTwo"]}[Content],
    DataTypeTwo = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceTwo,{{"#", type text}, {"Region", type any}, {"Desc.", type text}, {"Brand A", Int64.Type}, {"Brand B", Int64.Type}, {"Brand C", Int64.Type}}),

    //DataThree
    SourceThree = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataThree"]}[Content],
    DataTypeThree = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceThree,{{"#", type any}, {"Region", type text}, {"Desc.", type text}, {"Brand A", Int64.Type}, {"Brand B", Int64.Type}, {"Brand C", Int64.Type}}),

    //DataFour
    SourceFour = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="DataFour"]}[Content],
    DataTypeFour = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SourceFour,{{"#", type any}, {"Region", type text}, {"Desc.", type text}, {"Brand A", Int64.Type}, {"Brand B", Int64.Type}, {"Brand C", Int64.Type}}),

    //AppendingAllFourTables & Unpivoting
    Append = Table.Combine({DataTypeOne, DataTypeTwo, DataTypeThree, DataTypeFour}),
    DataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Append,{{"#", Int64.Type}, {"Region", type text}, {"Desc.", type text}, {"Brand A", Int64.Type}, {"Brand B", Int64.Type}, {"Brand C", Int64.Type}}),
    UnpivotData = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(DataType, {"#", "Region", "Desc."}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
    UnpivotData
```

---

[image]

---

• Change the Table name as Desiredtbl before importing it back into Excel.

• When importing, you can either select Existing Sheet with the cell reference you want to place the table or you can simply click on NewSheet

[image]

---